# how to understand and use spring fuse with eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

i am trying to build a project using spring fuse, so far i understand that "spring fuse is an online code generator for data oriented applications based on celerio" what i don't understand is what does it have to do with apache camel and OSGi? maybe nothing! but all the tutorials that i have found (and they are so rare) are talking about Apache camel and OSGi,  for example [this](http://fusesource.com/docs/ide/2.1/tutorials/RiderTutorialCreate.html) tutorial is starting with Creating a New Route and i do not know what does it mean by route ?!
is there any tutorial for rookies that also contains integration with eclipse?
may seem too obvious but "i am dying here man!" (quote cosmo kramer in seinfeld )

Answer (score 1):

Camel and OSGI are just some architectural issues on this tutorial and it is irrelevant to Fuse.:) 
In this tutorial , it is building a route project with help of camel.
And the OSGI is used for building a dynamic component model :)

Comment: any comment on which tutorial to read? is it just a first-time build tool or can do more tricks on the run?